# TCalendarView Month changed event

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl

I am using Embarcadero C++Builder 10.3 and VCL. I have a `TCalendarView` on the page. The calendar displays well, and I am able to implement changing of the colours for the days.

However, there doesn't seem to be any way to detect that the month has been changed when the up and down month arrows are clicked.

The month will change on the display, but unless I click on a day in the new month, I get no event to tell me that the new month has been selected.  The `Date` returned by the Calender also doesn't change until a new day is selected, so I cannot determine the displayed month without requiring another click.

This is annoying, as it means I cannot highlight special days on a particular month until someone clicks on one of the days of the newly visible month.

Does anyone have a workaround, so I can determine the month that is currently visible on the component, so it can be highlighted automatically?

Comment: But Barry, assuming you are in month view looking at a few days from previous month, each day of selected month and a few days grayed of next month. When you change the month with the up arrow and down arrows, you get a `OnDrawDayItem()` event for each day. It is in this event you are supposed to modify the drawing of each day as needed, no?

Comment: (Sorry for Delphi code) E.g. in event `OnDrawDayItem`, that is:  `CalendarView1DrawDayItem()` : `if CalendarViewViewInfo.Date = StrToDate('24.3.2023') then DrawParams.BorderColor := clRed;` draws a red frame around the day.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your comment Tom. I now have a solution based around what you have suggested.  I wanted an event when it changes so that I could do one fetch from the database for the entire calendar view, rather than one per day.  The postgresql database we use is fast if on the LAN but sometime we access remote and then it is very slow.  Minimising the number of queries speeds things up a lot.

Like you suggested I realised that if I looked at the date for cell [0,0] I would have the starting date for the 42 days of calendar I am displaying.  If this date changes in the `OnDrawDayItem` event, then I use this as the trigger for my fetch from the database and I retrieve the data for the 42 days whenever this changes.

I have implemented this now and found this works very well and I am able to detect when the month or year have been adjusted and update the calendar display accordingly.

I set an initial invalid date for the start of the month display.

When the `OnDrawDayItem` event fires for Cell[0,0] I compare the cell date with my stored date value and if they are different, I record the new date as my starting value and fetch the 42 days of data which is then parsed to give highlighting information for each of the days in the current calendar.

If the date has not changed, I use my retained highlighting information from the last fetch.

Comment: Sounds like a good strategy.